# Remove reputation cap for private beta sites?

Tags: discussion

While this site is still being defined and created, reputation is very important. It allows us to start getting up there and making the site what it is. However, reputation limits in private beta seem to be dumb. Every upvote counts. We should get the rewards for that upvote. Once we go into public beta, I see having a rep cap. But for private beta? We really need to define the site and create it first. We need to have moderation.

I propose that this private beta's reputation cap be removed while this site is still a fledgeling.

Answer (score 9):

What's the point of having points if this site doesn't even make it past the first few days?

I would worry more about keeping this site from being closed for being an elaborate catch-all site than trying to collect as many internet points as possible.

Everyone should be taking this time to ask questions, and figure out what the scope is, and what quality is expected from questions and answers. You don't need points for that.

Answer (score 9):

Gaining reputation takes time. It takes a steady stream of useful contributions. The purpose of the reputation cap is to keep individuals from receiving an undue number of abilities for one crazy-popular post. You don't want users coming out of the private beta with a bunch of abilities they might not have received otherwise. The private beta is a type of "dress rehearsal" before we open this site to the public. As such, you want the activities and behaviors to be as much as possible like the actual site.

In a bigger picture sense, reputation (as a metaphor) is the currency that drives the economy of this site. And for that currency to have value, it has to be a limited resource. You can imagine, for example, that someone who *REALLY* wants this site to succeed would simply go around up-voting the top users simply to get people up there.  That sounds like a good strategy on the surface, but how would folks know if their their content is being well accepted (and correct) if the up-vote means nothing?

Up-votes and reputation are a limited resource, so you have to pick and choose the best of the content you feel is deserving — and that is by design.